# MongoDB aggregation $elemMatch inside $lookup stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection that is looking like this:

```
{
    players: [
        {uuid: "A"},
        {uuid: "B"}
    ]
},
{
    players: [
        {uuid: "A"},
        {uuid: "C"}
    ]
},
{
    players: [
        {uuid: "D"},
        {uuid: "E"}
    ]
}
```

I want to use results of a previous aggregation stage and now find all documents where a player shows up, using a `$lookup` stage:

```
from: "collection",
pipeline: [
    {
        $match: {
            players: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    uuid: "$playerId" 
                }
            }
            //using "players.uuid": "$playerId" doesn't work either
        }
    }
],
as: "field"
```

The input to my `$lookup` stage looks like this:

```
{ 
    "playerId" : "A"
}
{ 
    "playerId" : "B"
}
{ 
    "playerId" : "C"
}
```

This query returns an empty array in `field`. It seems like `$uuid` is not getting evaluated correctly, because if I exchange `$uuid` with a hardcoded value (e.g. `A`), this query returns results.

I have also tried using the `let` property, this gave me the same result.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post from collection with sample document

Comment: The top portion of my post contains sample documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the documents you've provided.  I believe this might work for you:

I've used `$lookup` to do a join onto the collection which holds the `playerId`, which creates an `array` called `field`. I then use `$unwind` to extract all the array elements from both `field` and `player`. Finally I use `$cond` to crosscheck if both values match.

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
{ $lookup : {
    from: "bar",
    localField: "players.uuid",
    foreignField: "playerId",
    as: "field"
    } },
    { $unwind : "$players" },
    { $unwind : "$field" },
    { $project : { 
      "players": 1, 
      "field" : 1, 
      "isMatch": { 
      "$cond": [ { "$eq": ["$players.uuid", "$field.playerId"] }, 1, 0 ] 
      } } }
    ])
```

I've purposely left the output verbose..

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f534b337e8d2b97ff2ffb"),
    "players" : {
        "uuid" : "A"
    },
    "field" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f5374337e8d2b97ff2ffe"),
        "playerId" : "A"
    },
    "isMatch" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f534b337e8d2b97ff2ffb"),
    "players" : {
        "uuid" : "A"
    },
    "field" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f539b337e8d2b97ff2fff"),
        "playerId" : "B"
    },
    "isMatch" : 0.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f534b337e8d2b97ff2ffb"),
    "players" : {
        "uuid" : "B"
    },
    "field" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f5374337e8d2b97ff2ffe"),
        "playerId" : "A"
    },
    "isMatch" : 0.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f534b337e8d2b97ff2ffb"),
    "players" : {
        "uuid" : "B"
    },
    "field" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f539b337e8d2b97ff2fff"),
        "playerId" : "B"
    },
    "isMatch" : 1.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f5356337e8d2b97ff2ffc"),
    "players" : {
        "uuid" : "A"
    },
    "field" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f5374337e8d2b97ff2ffe"),
        "playerId" : "A"
    },
    "isMatch" : 1.0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f5356337e8d2b97ff2ffc"),
    "players" : {
        "uuid" : "A"
    },
    "field" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f53a8337e8d2b97ff3000"),
        "playerId" : "C"
    },
    "isMatch" : 0.0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f5356337e8d2b97ff2ffc"),
    "players" : {
        "uuid" : "C"
    },
    "field" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f5374337e8d2b97ff2ffe"),
        "playerId" : "A"
    },
    "isMatch" : 0.0
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f5356337e8d2b97ff2ffc"),
    "players" : {
        "uuid" : "C"
    },
    "field" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f53a8337e8d2b97ff3000"),
        "playerId" : "C"
    },
    "isMatch" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: It is a field name I would like to join on, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Joba Can you please update your OP with an example of this collection too please. Then I can setup a test and see if I can help. At present I only have half of your problem :-)

Comment: Updated the OP and clarified my example

Comment: But why initial request by topic started does not work?